# debian libvirt 2 subnets

Tags: networking, libvirt, subnets

I want to create a network like this:

[image: network design]

I have a virtual host which is conntected to my physical router with eth0 and ip4 address 192.168.178.100. I create a virtual machine dmz which connects 'direct' to my router via my physical device eth0 on the virtual host:

```
<network connections='1'>
  <name>direct</name>
  <uuid>379d4687-445e-4bc6-8354-b555c7f18b15</uuid>
  <forward dev='eth0' mode='bridge'>
    <interface dev='eth0' connections='1'/>
  </forward>
</network>
```

On my virtual machine i create a second nic eth1 which is connected on a virtual network virbr-local:

```
<network ipv6='yes'>
  <name>local</name>
  <uuid>d31b2e0d-810b-4ba0-8ac4-02bc53746142</uuid>
  <bridge name='virbr-local' stp='on' delay='0'/>
  <mac address='52:54:00:92:06:5c'/>
  <domain name='local.box'/>
  <dns>
    <forwarder addr='192.168.178.1'/>
  </dns>
  <ip address='10.0.0.1' netmask='255.0.0.0'>
    <dhcp>
      <range start='10.0.0.100' end='10.0.0.255'/>
      <host mac='52:54:00:51:31:86' ip='10.0.0.30'/>
    </dhcp>
  </ip>
  <route address='10.0.0.0' prefix='8' gateway='10.0.0.30'/>
</network>
```

Now I want to create a second virtual machine which connects to the internet through the virtual machine dmz on the virbr-local subnet. Is there a way to accomplish this kind of setup?

My routing table on the virtual host looks likes this:

```
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
default         fritz.box       0.0.0.0         UG    0      0        0 eth0
10.0.0.0        *               255.0.0.0       U     0      0        0 virbr-local
10.0.0.0        10.0.0.30       255.0.0.0       UG    1      0        0 virbr-local
192.168.178.0   *               255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 eth0
```

I appreciate some help.

Answer (score 0):

Asside from setting up routing on the DMZ machine and adding two interfaces mapped to `direct` and `local`. It should be just a matter of setting up DNAT on the DMZ.

All machines connecting through the DMZ would need their interface as:

```
<interface type='network'>
  <source network='local'/>
  <!-- Other stuff -->
</interface>
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I did setup dmz with the local en direct network like this. And the www virtual machine only with the local network. I can ping the www virtual machine form the dmz virtual machine and v.v.  I setup a DNAT on the dmz

    "-A PREROUTING -d 10.0.0.30/32 -j DNAT --to-destination 192.168.178.44"

But when I try a traceroute on then www virtual machine I get a Network unreachable
    traceroute www.xs4all.nl
    traceroute to www.xs4all.nl (194.109.6.92), 30 hops max, 46 byte packtes
    1traceroute: sendto: Network unreachable

So I must missing something.

Comment: According to the local netmask in your question, shouldn't the DNAT network be `10.0.0.0/8`? `10.0.0.30/32` implies host only... It would never apply to other hosts on the same network.

Comment: I changed the setting in the iptables config and restart iptables. It has no effect. Stil the same message. When I do a tcpdump on eth1 of the dmz virtual machine I see nothing. So it seems there is no communication to dmz virtual machine at all. Maybe the route config on the host?